# Change visible all buttons create dynamically in loop if I clicked on certain C#

Tags: c#, arrays, button, click, visible

I've got this problem:
In the loop I create buttons:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < poz; i++)
            {
                
                for (int j = 0; j < pion; j++)
                {
                    
                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.Size = new Size(30, 30);
                    button.Location = new Point(30 * (i + 1), 30 * (j + 1) + 50);
                    button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
                    Controls.Add(button);


                }
            }
```

And when I clicked on button, it change visible to false:

```
            protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Button button = sender as Button;
                button.Visible = false;
            }
```

But finally, I want to achieve when if I clicked on certain button, all the buttons in this loop change visible to false. My condition is:

```
           for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
            {
                if (x[k] == i && y[k] == j)
                {
                    //here buttons change visible to false
                }
            }
```

...When m is count of elements in x and y arrays, and i is number of buttons horizontally and j is number of buttons in vertical.

I tried using a variable that determines if the button was clicked and many different methods, but none worked. I expect a simple solution.

Comment: Have you tried adding the buttons to a list?

Comment: You need to have the `Buttons` in some sort of list so that you can loop over that to access each of them. If the form structure allows it, one option could be to add a `Panel` to the form and then add the `Buttons` to the `Panel` instead of directly to the form. You can then loop over all the `Buttons` in the `Controls` collection of that `Panel`. If that's not possible or not preferable, just use a `List<Button>`.